# Manage AD with Powershell without module on win XP

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-xp

Is it possible to connect and manage Active Directory through Powershell v2 on Windows XP without Active Directory Module ? I need to import csv file to AD and overwrite few attributes? If not can I do it with VB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `ADSI` is available in PowerShell 2.0 (and VB) on Windows XP. Read more about `ADSI` at [Managing Active Directory with Windows PowerShell](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-tutorial-active-directory/)

However, I would highly recommend  a module like [`Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell`](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) when managing AD.

Comment: Will I be able to execute this script later on a computer without Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell ? What is required ?

Comment: Scripts are like source code in programming. You need all resources available every time you compile(run) it, so no, you will need to have the Quest module installed on every computer where you want to use the script. If you choose `ADSI` to access AD, you will be able to run it on any computer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will use ADSI then.